# Using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] with multi referers

Tags: php

I am trying to (somehow) secure an Ajax - PHP connection. using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` I need to validate the `HTTP_REFERER` for two pages as `products.php` (all products) and `product.php` (single product). Can I use PHP `in_array()` to handle this, something like:

```
$referers  = array("https://example.com/products.php", "https://example.com/product.php");

if (@isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $referers))
  {
     
  }
```

If so, how can I handle the dynamic URL parameters with  `https://example.com/product.php` ? for example if I have `https://example.com/product.php?sku=96` or `https://example.com/product.php?sku=300` this is not gonna work with `in_array()` as it is different than what are listed in the `$referers` even though the source are correct.

Comment: you should define allowed origins instead , search about CORS headers in php

Comment: Don't count on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, it's not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not guaranteed to be set and not guaranteed to be the original referer.  You might use a session variable:

```
//products.php and product.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['ref'] = basename(__FILE__);

//other.php
session_start();
$referers  = array("products.php", "product.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['ref']) && in_array($_SESSION['ref'], $referers))
  {

  }
```

Keep in mind that if you hit the `products.php` and then `another.php` and then `other.php`  that `$_SESSION['ref']` will still be `products.php`, so you either want to set it in all files or `unset()` it in other files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$trustedReferers = array("https://example.com/products.php", "https://example.com/product.php");
$referer = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
    $infos = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $referer = "{$infos['scheme']}://{$infos['host']}:{$infos['port']}{$infos['path']}";
}

if (in_array($referer, $trustedReferers)) {
    echo "Trusted referer";
} else {
    echo "Untrusted referer";
}
```

By the way, I suggest make changes the business logic that only restrict the domain of the referer. Then the site is easier to maintain.